# Consolidated search platform for company documents (federal and state)

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, state, federal

*Please excuse due to lack of knowledge in the area of private company filings in the US.*

My assumption is that private companies in the US must make 2 separate returns (at federal and state)
For federal, we can use [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/) platform to search for filing/documents. But when it comes to State, we need to visit individual state portal ( for eg  [for California](https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/), [and for Nevada](https://esos.nv.gov/EntitySearch/OnlineEntitySearch) etc) to download documents such as annual returns/certificate of incorporation etc.

I am in process of building a search feature which help user to search/download all returns across federal and state portals. Unfortunately, I am finding it difficult to perform search across various states since there is no unified identifier (something like CIK for EDGAR) handy for me to perform this search.

**Question:** Is there any provider (open source or paid) available out there who could abstract this complexity of search. Something like an API which would perform a consolidated search across various states and return the result ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCorporates and CorporationsWiki are the best that I know of. They're certainly incomplete and out of date at times though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).